# Redirect when unAuthorize

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 2.x. I am handling Access Denied page for unAuthorize (by roles) pages.
This is my **Admin Controller**:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
}
```

This is my others role for HR and Fin:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "HRManager,Finance")]
public class SalaryController : Controller
{
}
```

I put code **AddAuthentication** in ConfigureServices (Startup.cs)

```
services.AddAuthentication ()
        .Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie (options => {

            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";

        });
```

When users from HR & Finance role try to access Admin menu, I expect that those users will redirect to **AccessDenied** page but It don't. It redirect to

```
/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAdmin
```

I've also prepared an empty AccessDenied.cshtml page but it never reach it.

Any solution for this issue ?
Or I miss something in **AddAuthentication** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for .net core 2.0

> add this in to your startup.cs in ConfigureServices method

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn");
```